# How to check if partials does not exist? (handlebars)?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

When "MY BLOCK", was not registered with Handlebars.registerPartial
How to check if it not exist and throw error.

```
{{#"MY BLOCK"}}
'123',
{{/"MY BLOCK"}}'
```

Answer (score 2):

It`s an old question and I hope you had found your solution and only for the records, you can do the same for partials:

```
if(!("MY BLOCK" in Handlebars.partials)){
  throw "error";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In javascript i could check

```
if(!("MY BLOCK" in Handlebars.helpers)){
 throw "error";
}
```